# Like / Send popup "flyout" hidden in FB tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, xfbml, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to implement a send button on my custom FB tab app.

Using the XFBML share button works, but when you click on it, the pop-up (aka "flyout") gets hidden due to the overflow: hidden; css.
Changing the overflow attribute to visible, for example, doesn't have a effect (probably cause I'm telling FB to resize the tab:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
    }
</script>`

Screenshot of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHH1a.png (I'm a new user, not allowed inline images)

Is there a way of telling the box to display on top of the right FB sidebar or on the left of the button instead of the right?

Do I need to create a dialogue box with share & like buttons? (this might become problematic as I intend to display a send button next to each row).

Link to raw tab index.php : http://openair.co.nz/facebook/events/

Answer (score 0):

You may consider positioning the Send button to the left side of the tab iframe, and make sure that the bottom send button has enough space below itself to open a popup without losing it again. No other known solutions (my opinion)

Comment: The Google Plus seems to be able to generate a popup that breaches the iFrame area, seems a lot smarter too in terms of automatic layout.